# How can I encrypt keystore password in wildlfy8

Tags: ssl, wildfly, jboss5.x

In Jboss5 server.xml file has https configuration in  is

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
   keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/abc.jks"
keystorePass="base123" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

Here my keystore file is abc.jks and password is base123.

I used below to encrypt my keystorepass , in jboss5
`<connector....
securityDomain="java:/jaas/encrypt-keystore-password"
SSLImplementation="org.jboss.net.ssl.JbossImplementation"/>`

In this I created *.password file to encrypt password
Kindly refer below link
[Encrypt keystore password in jboss5](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-%20%20US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/pdf/Security_Guide/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Pla%20%20tform-5-Security_Guide-en-US.pdf)

In wildlfy8 ssl configuration is,

```
<server-identities>
    <ssl>
      <keystore path="abc.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="base123" alias="mycert" key-password="base123"/>
     </ssl>
</server-identities>
```

So I wanted to encrypt my key store password in wildfly8.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the provided vaultTool : https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/MaskingPasswordsForWildFlyUsingNon-interactiveVaultTool